# How to create a reusable type of a type expression?

Tags: angular, typescript

Say we have a couple functions like this with the same return type:

```
private isFormArrayOrGroup(formControl: AbstractControl): formControl is UntypedFormGroup | UntypedFormArray
```

How can I make a reusable type of `formControl is UntypedFormGroup | UntypedFormArray`

Also: what is the correct naming for this sort of type?

This is not valid: `type FormType = formControl is UntypedFormGroup | UntypedFormArray`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make a *type* out of the `is` expression. That's only valid as part of a return type annotation for a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

You can make a type alias for the union `UntypedFormGroup | UntypedFormArray`:

```typescript
type UntypedFormStuff = UntypedFormGroup | UntypedFormArray;
```

...then use it:

```typescript
private isFormArrayOrGroup(formControl: AbstractControl): formControl is UntypedFormStuff
```